# Cyclisation of acetone on reaction with conc. H2SO4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Mechanism for reaction of acetone with concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$:

The product is supposed to be mesitylene, and on various sites I found the reason behind it to be aldol condensation And some sites provided me with unusual products( as for a high school student)

- Does this reaction have a reasonable reaction mechanism or do we just have to mug this up?
- What are these cyclisation kinda mechanisms called?
- Do they have a category that is to be understood?

Comment: Yeah, it's standard acid catalysed aldol condensation.

Comment: Do an acid-catalyzed aldol condensation to get (E)-4,6-dimethylhepta-3,5-dien-2-one. Form the vinylogous enol with a Z-geometry then cyclization by either double bond addition to the carbonyl or hexatriene cyclization. Work on it awhile!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have noticed that your question received a downvote. This was probably because you did not show any effort toward a solution of the question. I posted in a Comment some clues to assist you in a solution. In the interim an Answer was posted that showed the compounds formed in the reaction of acetone with H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> but it did not illustrate a mechanism for the formation of mesitylene, which was your question. Here is my contribution to your understanding.
The reaction between the keto form of acetone **1a** and its enol **1b** forms aldol **2**. Acid-catalyzed dehydration of **2** via the enol **3** leads to mesityl oxide **4**. The loss of water from **3** may be stepwise but, to save space, I have presented the loss of water in a single operation. The third unit of acetone is incorporated via the vinylogous enol **4b** to form the dienone **5a**. Enolization of **5a** forms **5b'** that allows rotation about the red single bond in **5a** and **5b'** to form conformation **5b"**. This species may cyclize by an allowed thermal electrocyclization to form cyclohexadiene **8** which is readily dehydrated by acid to mesitylene **9**. Alternatively, enol **5b'** may reketonize to **6** and undergo cyclization to cation **7** and thence on to mesitylene **9**. *continued...*
[image]
**Addendum:** An old name for acetone was mesite, the source of mesitylene. Read about it [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6z3EDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=etymology%20mesitylene&source=bl&ots=mnbpoPNvdi&sig=ACfU3U3jrVfA98232bVfDhErELDVdmieng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHv-rq-MnmAhUkZN8KHQwEAHUQ6AEwEXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=etymology%20mesitylene&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=-1JdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA355&lpg=PA355&dq=mesityl%20radical&source=bl&ots=yWNKUxcBlO&sig=ACfU3U1A6RFyIzk759Q3DZpuB4h297a20A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip_MXK-snmAhWFdN8KHUFdDtQQ6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=mesityl%20radical&f=false).

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful.. actually  I am a student and when I heard about acid cataylsed aldol and kinda freaked out cause i was taught that you identify aldol itself with Dil naoh/koh and heat.

Comment: Could this be performed with acetaldehyde to get benzene?

Comment: I came across this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100340/acetaldehyde-with-few-drops-of-concentrated-sulphuric-acid

Which... makes things confusing.

Comment: @McSuperbX1: What exactly is confusing you? Why not pose a new question.

Comment: @user55119 after 4a , why doesn't aldol directly happen on the right side methyl group (attached to the ketone group). It rather unexpectedly follows a "sort of" 1-4-michael addition mechanism. why does this happen ?

Comment: Certainly the yield of mesitylene is not 100%. Enol 4a is more stable than the enol toward the methyl, for what that is worth. You say "unexpectedly". Apparently, not to Mother Nature.  Base vs. acid-mediated reactions can go in different directions. The bromination of 2-butanone in base leads to a haloform reaction whereas in acid, bromination is autocatalytic  and bromination occurs at C3 via the more stable enol.

Answer (score 6):

Catalytic (acid or base) self-condensation of acetone is a very complex reaction, which has been analyzed several years ago (Ref.1). I don't have an access to the original article, yet, I recommend OP to find this article and read it carefully. Its abstract states that:

> Catalytic self-condensation of acetone is a very complex reaction and numerous products are possible via competitive self-condensation and cross-condensation between the same or different ketones that are formed in the reaction. All the major products of the reaction, diacetone alcohol, mesityl oxide, phorone, mesitylene, isophorone, 3,5-xylenol and 2,3,5-trimethylphenol find important industrial applications. The reaction is catalysed by acids as well as bases, and it can be carried out in both liquid and vapour phases. The selectivity of the reaction for the desired product is achieved by proper choice of catalyst and experimental conditions. This paper reviews the recent developments in the process of self-condensation of acetone, evaluating the significance of various parameters for obtaining the desired product.

Nonetheless, I found a sketch of condensation pathways of acetone from that article, which I depicted in following diagram:

[image: Autocondensation of Acetone]

As OP recognized, it is based on acid-catalyzed aldol condensation. Condensation of two molecules of acetone gives 4-methylpent-3-en-2-one (the trivial name of which is mesityl oxide) first. Keep in mind that since this is not a base catalyzed reaction, fair amount of 4-hydroxy-4-methylpent-2-one is also exist in the reaction mixture. However, these two compounds and acetone further undergo a plethora of other condensation to give several products, including mesitylene (see the diagram).

Nevertheless, the method is used to synthesize mesitylene (Ref.2) large scale, although the yield is poor (~15-20%).

**References:**

1. G. S. Salvapati, K. V. Ramanamurty, Mulpuri Janardanarao, “Selective catalytic self-condensation of acetone,” *Journal of Molecular Catalysis* **1989**, *54(1)*, 9-30 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-5102(89)80134-8).
2. Submitted by Roger Adams and R. W. Hufferd (Checked by H. T. Clarke and W. W. Hartman), “Mesitylene,” *Organic Syntheses, Coll. Vol. 1* **1941**, p.341 (*Org. Synth.* **1922**, *2*, 41) (DOI: 10.15227/orgsyn.002.0041).