# What is the product when alcohol is added to carbonyl compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, nucleophilicity

How do we know if, on adding alcohol to carbonyl compound:

1. nucleophilic addition reaction will take place

[image: r]

or

2. alcohol will take alpha hydrogen to form a carbanion and consequent
   aldol condensation will take place. Here B is alcohol (e.g. $\ce{EtOH}$)

[image]

Comment: Note the conditions and what other reagents are added - they are very important.

Comment: "Here B is alcohol (e.g. $\ce{EtOH}$)" Not exactly. What is it instead? The reaction mechanisms are totally different.

Comment: B is an alcohol. see the first step of aldol condensation.

Comment: @aaravm  Incorrect! B is an alkoxide - big difference.

Comment: oh yeah i hadnt realised that reagents were different. sorry!

Comment: You should have been more concerned with comparing ketal formation (1) with an [acid-catalyzed aldol condensation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125413/cyclisation-of-acetone-on-reaction-with-conc-h2so4/125452#125452).

Comment: @aaravm if you got your answer, feel free to make a self answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments, the second reaction reagent is not exactly an alcohol but an alkoxide. For example, $\ce{EtONa}$ and not $\ce{EtOH}$.

This makes the reaction condition for the second reaction basic whereas the first reaction is taking place in acidic conditions.